# How do I get my Hello World program to compile?

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

Basic Hello World Program not compiling on Linux (monodevelop)

I have been trying to get rid of this exception.I did not even type anything. All I did was hit the play button and I got this exception.

System.TypeInitializationException

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");

    }
}
```

}

I expected the program to display hello world like it would on windows but I cant seem to figure out what I need to do to get the program to run.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code; possibly something wrong with your development environment. Try VS Code with C# (OmniSharp) extension, and .NET Core

Comment: Please provide more detail exceptions, or screenshots is better.

Comment: You should read about mono. This will help you to compile c# code in a Linux environment.